# JPA/eclipselink and sybase kerberos

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, kerberos

I am trying to write a program using JPA which has to try to authenticate to sybase using kerberos.

Sybase example programs show that we need to specify the  properties
REQUEST_KERBEROS_SESSION and
SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME

what are the equivalent properties in eclipselink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to figure it out.

PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_PROPERTY+"REQUEST_KERBEROS_SESSION"
PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_PROPERTY+"SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME"

This is how we can specify in eclipselink.